# php fwrite text file go to next line not work

Tags: php, fwrite

I want save to txt file but next line not work

Code:

```
$text = '';
for(i=1;$i<10;$i++){
    $text .= $i."\n";
}

$file = fopen('text.txt','a');
fwrite($file,$text);
fclose($file);
```

Comment: What you mean by *pre line*?

Comment: Go to next line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `PHP_EOL` for jump new line. And your code is not working, because you missed `$` mark for `i=1`. It should be `$i=1`

```
$text = '';
for($i=1;$i<10;$i++){
    $text .= $i.PHP_EOL;
}

$file = fopen('text.txt','a');
fwrite($file,$text);
fclose($file);
```

Answer (score 0):

> If you want to have a new, empty line at the beginning of a file you can simply initializes `$text="\n";`

```
  <?php

    $text      = '' . PHP_EOL;
    for($i=1;$i<10;$i++){
        $text .= $i . PHP_EOL;
    }

    $file = fopen('text.txt','a');
    fwrite($file,$text);
    fclose($file);
```